# search text in remote html content with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I load a remote html file with jquery and tested that it comes perfectly. I stored that html content in `$secPage` and then try to search text in `td` in `$secPage`, but got empty.

```
$secPage = $(data);  
$('#content').html($secPage); // it works and shows data 
var result = $('td:contains("Ejendomsværdi:")',$secPage).next().text(); // returns empty
```

but if I test the same code with http://jsfiddle.net/ then got result.

```
var result = $('td:contains("Ejendomsværdi:")').next().text();  // it works in jsfiddle
```

That means, when I test with `$secPage` then it returns empty, but it should not be.

Please help ...

Answer (score 1):

As you say it's a remote file, I guess it means it comes from a different domain.

Then you can't do it : [cross domain protection rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) prevents you to read or change the content loaded from another domain (including port) unless the remote server allows it (using headers)

Comment: thanks, but it is not a xss issue because already comes and loads in my container div. but I dont want to load in div, want to search a specific td value. clear about my issue?

Comment: XSS protection **doesn't prevent load or display**. It prevents reading or changing the content in javascript.

Comment: but I have that data on my hand in a variable, so can I think the content is in my page now, because the content is in a variable. I am confused.

Comment: basically I am using this in my jquery mobile project, in jquery mobile we can overcome xss issue, otherwise I could not load the remote data. so, what is your suggestion?